# In Mysql how delete and update command works?

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql database I have a table:

```
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| user_id | int(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME    | varchar(20)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email   | varchar(20)      | NO   | PRI |         |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have the data :

```
+---------+--------+------------------+
| user_id | NAME   | email            |
+---------+--------+------------------+
|       1 | ap      | aa1@aol.com     |
|       3 | as      | aap@aol.com     |
|       4 | salini | salini@gmail.com |
+---------+--------+------------------+
```

Now My requirement:
I want to delete and set value of a row at a time..

suppose **I want to delete the name and update the email='saliniRoy@gmail.com where name=salini**

So I am using

```
UPDATE student
SET email='saliniRoy@gmail.com' & delete name
WHERE name=salini;
```

But it is not working..what i have to do then??

Comment: Your delete syntax is not correct (see the answer below), and you forgot to add quotation marks to `name='salini'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the name to blank:

```
UPDATE student
SET email='saliniRoy@gmail.com', name=''
WHERE name='salini';
```

or `null`

```
UPDATE student
SET email='saliniRoy@gmail.com', name=null
WHERE name='salini';
```

Comment: Thanks..It is working.I wanted to accept your answer but it is saying I have to wait 10 mins..Then I can accept your answer.